# Managing Included Footnotes in oolatex/htlatex/tex4ht

Tags: footnotes, include

I'm being diligent and doing all my work in LaTeX, unfortunately my supervisor prefers his work in Word for review. The easy way (or so I thought) was to use oolatex / tex4ht to convert my nice latex file into odt and into doc.

I have sections of my work separated out for management of multiple documents, with these brought into the main document with `\include{}`.

The problem has arisen that footnotes in these sections are not being processed separately, and are clobbering eachother, leading to errors like this

> `--- TeX4ht warning --- Multiple footnote texts for mark 1 ---`

This all makes sense and I understand why its happenning, but apart from bringing all my work into the same time (making it pretty much un-maintainable), what can I do to force oolatex to reprocess in-page footnotes?

**TL;DR `Include`d files causing footnote clobbering trying to turn tex->doc using oolatex**

Comment: Maybe problem is with some package that you are loading, I tried including of files with footnotes and it works well